# JAVA SWT Can't get the image relative path

Tags: java, image, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm stuck again on a problem concerning SWT using Java RCP.

### What I want :

I have a Composite in which I wanna load an Image in it.

### How it's currently done :

For this, I use a SWT Label, and call the method setImage(image). 
The image (img.jpg) is found in a directory called /img/ next to the /src/ one. The directory is added in the Build Path. Here's a screen to illustrate :
[directories](https://www.pixenli.com/images/1487/1487262090046459900.png)

I call this image as follows :

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/img/img.jpg");
ImageData imageData = new ImageData(is);
Label label = new Label(picRoom, SWT.NONE);
label.setImage(new Image(display, imageData));
```

### What's the problem ? :

[Once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256476/opening-a-new-window-with-java-rcp-and-swt), when I launch the project, everything goes right. The image loads and displays perfectly. But when I export it, the image doesn't anymore. The problem comes from the path actually. When I make an image as `new Image(display, absolutePathToTheImage)`, it loads even if exported. But I want the image in the /img/ directory, because if I launch the project from the .exe from another computer, I want it to have the picture, wherever it is (so in /img/).

I've tried many solutions across the internet (using URL in particular), but no one worked. And as I said, I need the image to be in the /img/ directory and to take the relative path. And, of course, to work after exporting the project as a .exe .

### Thanks in advance.

Kosnyru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your `img` directory is included in the `build.properties` includes so that it is included in the exported plugin.

Then use the `FileLocator` class to find the image using a relative path:

```
// Your plugin's bundle - there are several ways to get this
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

// Relative path in the plugin
String path = "/img/img.jpg";

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);

ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);

Image image = imageDesc.createImage();
```

Comment: Thanks again ! Indeed, even if my directory was in the build path, it wasn't in the includes in build.properties.
With the FileLocator, it works perfectly.
Again, thanks for all your knowledge !

Comment: It will work in testing when not in the build.properties, but it will **not** work when you export the RCP as the images won't be included in the build. It is a common mistake to forget this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is in `resources` directory, you can do something like:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/logo.png")));
```